# How to create unfixed length slice in Go

Tags: go, slice

I'm new in Go and I have 2 questions:

1 Let's say we have simple for loop written in C#:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<int> list = new List<int>();
        for (int i = 1; i < 10000; i++)
        {
            if (i % 5 == 0 && i % 3 == 0)
            {
                list.Add(i);
            }
        }
        foreach (int prime in list)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine(prime);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

If I wanted to do the same in Go I'll have to use slices. But how to do that?

2. Which of variable declaration form is more often used:
   short form (s:= 3) 
   or 
   long (var s int = 3)?

Comment: Slices are not fixed length in Go. This is the best article I have ever seen on slices: https://blog.golang.org/go-slices-usage-and-internals

Comment: On variable declaration style, I use the short form when initializing a variable to a certain value, but the long form when just declaring a variable which will be set later (or when declaring a package variable (i.e., outside of any block), which can only be done with `var`).

Comment: @seeker there are three answers already check and if any of them help accept the answer other wise comment here as to what is missing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Go arrays have their place, but they're a bit inflexible, so you don't see them too often in Go code. Slices, though, are everywhere . They build on arrays to provide great power and convenience.

Slice is not of fixed length. It is flexible .

You may declare an empty slice as following

```
list := make([]int, 0)
list := []int{}
var list []int
```

Here is how you may right the above function in go

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)


func main() {
        var list []int
        for i:=0;i<10000;i++ {
            if i %5 == 0 && i % 3 == 0 {
                list = append(list, i)
            }
        } 
        for _, val := range list {
            fmt.Println(val)
        }
}
```

Here is the play link [play](https://play.golang.org/p/gE7Gw54q_b)

Comment: @seeker check this and if this helps you , accept the anwer

Comment: It's also important to point out that, if you already know the length of the slice you want to create, you should specify that value instead of zero in the call to `make([]int, 150)`. This is more efficient for the compiler, which has to create a new backing array every time you append beyond the bounds of the backing array. By specifying the length in the `make` call (150 in this case), your slice will contain all zero'd values for every index up to 150. You can then assign new values like: `list[4] = 123` instead of calling `append`

Comment: @daltonclaybrook absolutely , here i was trying to give a sample so that  he  may start using slices

Answer (score 2):

1) Create a slice with:

```
list := make([]int, 0)
```

Append to a slice with:

```
list = append(list, i)
```

2) I think there is no single answer to your second question. It depends on how and where the variable is used.

Answer (score 0):

For 2)

```cs
var foo int = 3 // I want a int variable
bar := foo // bar will be the same type with foo
```